# can't login into google in online accounts section

Tags: online-accounts

I'm on pop os but it's based on Ubuntu so the solution should be the same 
I was able to login to google via online accounts section then it said your session has expired and then when I logged out to add it again it shows nothing[image]

Comment: I have a similar problem. After I input my email and password the popup says Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app.

Comment: That's not the same problem as mine but I solved mine by disabling webkit driver

Comment: WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue in 23.04, It was solved by pasting Arian's (on the comments on the post) answer into the terminal and continuing to log in bearing in mind to keep the terminal open until you have entered the password.

```
WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center
```