# Gnome Web crashes/freezes when logging into google account from settings menu

Tags: gnome, login, 22.04, email

I am trying to add a google account to my ubuntu 22.04 installation. The account I want to add is my university email which is maintained via google and has a google drive associated with it etc. My aim is to have shell incorporation of the google drive. I have a regular gmail account that I've connected with no issue and I have in the past been able to link the university based account in 20.04 without issue.

When I go to add the account through the settings menu, gnome web pops up for the login, I enter my university on the gmail and am redirected to the university's login page, where if I type in the username field and then try to tab or click to the password field the browser freezes. As an experiment I tried visiting this login page with 'gnome web' installed via the snap store, and it too behaves the same way on this page (it does give an actual crash page and say to report to developers rather than quietly freezing).

Does anyone know if there is another way to add the account possibly through the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Running gnome control center from the terminal and using it to login seems to do the trick

```
WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center
```

From: [can't login into google in online accounts section](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222378/cant-login-into-google-in-online-accounts-section)